# CSS - last-child property is not working

Tags: css

As per http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp 
When i am trying to apply :last-child for my code, the last child color is applyin to all childs. Last child should apply blue color rest of childs to gray color.

http://jsfiddle.net/rARwn/

Comment: No. Try again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Your JS Fiddle is doing what your CSS specifies; what result were you expecting that isn't met by the Fiddle? What, in short, does "the result is not that what I expected" mean? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correct give `last-child` to `th` not to his child. Write like this:

```
th:last-child .inner{background-color:lightblue}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rARwn/3/

Answer (score 1):

***"The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent."***

Read it carefully and then look at your code carefully. Each of your `DIV`s are the only child of the `TH` and thus all of them are also "the last child". That's why all are blue.

Your last CSS line should be:

```
th:last-child > div.inner{background-color:lightblue}
```

Answer (score 0):

:last-child applies to the last child of the parent you are applying the rule to.

Your `.inner` DIVs are all the last child of their parent (th). So the rule is applied to every div with that class.

Try something like:

```
tr :last-child div.inner { background-color:lightblue; }
```

That should do the job.

Comment: No, it's purely stylistic and personal. It looks tidier to me, though; but, again, purely personal preference.